# remove records in column which start with non-numbers in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with 3 columna , I want to perform sanity check on column OIB to remove the observations under OIB which start with non-number.

Sample DF is as below : and i want to remove 3 row which has OIB starting from non-number.

```
   subscriber_id          msisdn         oib

1:    BP12192064 385989105724 19958945074

2:    KP12192064 385989105774 09958945074

3:    KP12192064 385989105774 A9958945074
```

I tried in R  as below :

```
sym <- unique(df[!substr(oib, 1, 1) %in% (0:9), list(symb = substr(oib, 1, 1))])

df <- df[!substr(oib, 1, 1) %in% symbols[, symb]]
```

I want the above code in Python with expected output as:

```
subscriber_id          msisdn         oib

1:    BP12192064 385989105724 19958945074

2:    KP12192064 385989105774 09958945074
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `isnumeric` or `isdigit`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"subscriber_id": ["BP12192064", "KP12192064",  "KP12192064"],
                   "msisdn": ["385989105724", "385989105774", "385989105774"],
                   "oib": ["19958945074", "09958945074", "A9958945074"]})

print(df[df["oib"].str[0].str.isnumeric()])
print("--")
print(df[df["oib"].str[0].str.isdigit()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isin` with `string.digits`:

```
from string import digits

df[df['oib'].str[0].isin(list(digits))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[~df.oib.str.contains('[A-Za-z\W]', regex=True)]
```

**Output**

```
subscriber_id        msisdn          oib
1:    BP12192064  385989105724  19958945074
2:    KP12192064  385989105774  09958945074
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `^` for start of string and `\d` for match numbers:

```
df = df[df['oib'].str.contains('^\d')]
print (df)
   subscriber_id        msisdn          oib
1:    BP12192064  385989105724  19958945074
2:    KP12192064  385989105774  09958945074
```